# Jquery get all next siblings length

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do something very basic, but for some reason it isn't working.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-left roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
    <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-0-0.jpg');
         background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:bottom;">
    </section>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-right roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
    <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-1-0.jpg');
         background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:bottom;">
    </section>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-left roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
    <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-0-1.jpg');
         background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:top;">
    </section>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-right roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
    <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-1-1.jpg');
         background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:top;">
    </section>
</div>
```

When I select the first instance of `$(".roll")` using `$(".roll").eq(0)` (there are 4 in total, or 3 starting from a zero index) I want to know using jquery how many more roll siblings are after it. I should get 3, but I get 1.

Why so?

```
$(".roll").eq(0).next(".roll").length
```

Output :

> 1

Comment: You should be using `.nextAll()`.

Comment: `$(".roll").eq(0).nextAll('.roll').length`

Comment: You are using `.next()` which will return you only 1 element, instead of `.next()` try `.nextAll();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next()` will get the immediate sibling, you've to use `.nextAll(".roll")` instead to get all the sibligs with class `roll` :

```
$(".roll").eq(0).nextAll(".roll").length
```

Hope this helps.

```js
console.log( $(".roll").eq(0).nextAll(".roll").length );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-left roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
  <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-0-0.jpg');background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:bottom;">
  </section>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-right roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
  <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-1-0.jpg');background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:bottom;">
  </section>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-left roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
  <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-0-1.jpg');background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:top;">
  </section>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 bbb b-right roll" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
  <section class="overlay first" style="background:url('/css/rollsright-1-1.jpg');background-size:cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:top;">
  </section>
</div>
```